# Update gets stuck unpacking bad package, won't continue without it

Tags: 10.10, update-manager, software-sources

Removing the package from cache, and disabling Recommended Updates in Software Sources gives me an error saying I need to install this package.

I've tried to update several times, but it keeps hanging on unpacking the ubuntu-sso-client package. Which forces me to hard-reset to unlock the package manager.

I've tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

No errors

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken
```

Wants me to reinstall said package, resulting in it hanging

Removing the package:

```
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-sso-client_1.0.8-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Results in the same effect, it re-downloads then hangs

I can de-select Recommended Updates but I get error messages when I try to update again:

```
E: The package ubuntu-sso-client needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Which won't let me continue

Finally re-enabling the source, I try to remove ubuntu-sso

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-sso-client
```

It removes a bunch of other packages but complains about the package:

```
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-sso-client (--remove): 
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should 
reinstall it before attempting a removal.
```

Reinstalling ubuntu-sso-client hangs :(

I'm at my wits end, any ideas? I would be nice to install all the other updates but this one is preventing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dpkg --force-help`. And let the Force be with you.